# Why DID estimator is ATT?

Tags: difference-in-difference

A generalized DID has the equation as below

$Y_{it}$ = $\alpha$ + $\beta$ $(Leniency Law)_{kt}$ + $\delta$$X_{ikt}$ + $\theta$$_t$ + $\gamma$$_i$ +$\epsilon$$_{it}$

where *i*,*k*, and *t* index firms, countries, and years respectively. $X_{ikt}$ is a vector of the different firm, country, and industry control, while $\gamma$ and $\theta$ are firm and year fixed effects.

From [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/529903/319998) of Ariel,

> **$\beta$** is the average difference between pre- and post for the
> treated population. Because the ATT is the effect on the treated
> population of the intervention. Remember, DID is using the common
> trends assumption to try to tell us what would have happened to the
> treated population had they not been treated. It then compares the
> realized treated outcomes to the predicted untreated counterfactual

I am wondering if **$\beta$** is ATT, meaning that we did not mention control group in our explanation, so if we did not mention, why we include the control group into our regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-period DID is typically taken to estimate the ATT. This can easily be seen by doing out the expectations. Consider the specification at the unit $i$ level,

$$Y_i = \alpha + \gamma G_i + \theta T_i + \beta D_i + \epsilon_i$$

Here we use $G_i\in\{0,1\}$ to denote the group and $T_i \in \{0,1\}$ to denote the period. And $D_i = G_iT_i$ denotes treatment status.

Then to extract the treatment effect $\beta$ (and determine what it is) we will look at the potential outcomes when the group and period indicators are switched on. We have the potential outcome for the control as,

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i(0)|G_i=1,T_i=1]=\alpha + \gamma + \theta$$

And for treated,

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i(1)|G_i=1,T_i=1]=\mathbb{E}[Y_i(0)|G_i=1,T_i=1]+\beta$$

So we have,

$$\beta = \mathbb{E}[Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)|G_i=1,T_i=1]=\mathbb{E}[Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)|D_i=1]=ATT$$

In the case of a generalized DID estimator where there are multiple periods and multiple groups whose treatment status can be switched on at different times the answer is more complicated. As I wrote in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/529497/321865) the generalized DID can always be broken down into a weighted average of two-period DIDs. Each of these will exhibit an ATT. But overall, you will have estimated an average of ATTs. The exact interpretation of this is a little bit uncertain. Under a constant treatment assumption (which is very strong) this will indeed be the ATT. However, usually, that is not the case.

[Goodman-Bacon (2018)](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w25018/w25018.pdf) provides a little more study of how to interpret this. See section 2 of the attached paper.